# Filament PHP Roles and Permissions, Policy not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

i am having issues with getting the spatie roles and permissions running in Filament php with the package from spatie and Althinect/filament-spatie-roles-permissions, but i am not sure where the issue is located.
I have installed everything according the instructions and i have added a Super Admin based on the instruction and everything is working fine. When I add now a role with specific permissions (permissions generated via artisan permission:sync) and add a user to the role, the user has no access. I have also changed the view method within the policy to return true instead of the can('view_fault') and then the rights are correct. Does anyone have any idea what there is missing?
Thanks for your help. Armin

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Fault;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class FaultPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Fault  $fault
     * @return bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, Fault $fault): bool
    {
        return $user->can('view_fault');
    }
```

after several different checks, it seems that the `can()` helper is not working, if I use `hasPermissionTo()` the system finds the related permission. Anyone who can help?